# z-index on fixed position does not work in chrome

Tags: html, css

I need help and suggestion about z-index does not work on some layers as it works in all the other browsers. Here is a demo so you can see as well.

[demo here](http://cssdesk.com/Ufz9r)

IN my example, the menu is at the top and the menu blue background below the slide image. When a user scroll till the end of the slide image the blue background appears.

One more thing, it also not working in ie7.

Any help and suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change z-index:0 to z-index:-1 on .slide-img :P

Comment: Thank Ikillnukes! This will bring the blue bg on top of the slide in chrome. And I need it behind the slide until a user scroll the page. Please recheck it again in chrome. For me it does not work.

Comment: I still have this problem only in chrome. Would somebody please help me in this issue? [Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cc8yf/)

Comment: It is solved thanks! with the help of @amoss and Paulie. See the  [Solved Demo Here](http://codepen.io/anon/full/iKljy) Thanks!